# Program doesn't see my video (CSS,EXPRESS)

Tags: css, node.js, express

I need to add video. But the default way to make a path to it doesn't works. I guess, I need to add somewhere alse this path, but i can't understand where.

I already tried to put video in folder with my singup.hbs , but it doesn't work

signup.hbs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="site-style">
        <div class="fullscreen-bg">
            <div class="main-log">
                <form id="signup" name="signup" method="post" action="/signup">
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input class="text" name="email" type="email" />
                    <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                    <input name="firstname" type="text" />
                    <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
                    <input name="lastname" type="text" />
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input name="password" type="password" />
                    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <video loop muted autoplay poster="video/plane.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video" width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
                <source src="club_v.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[structure_of_program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUy38.png)

video_v.mp4 is in a folder: \app\views

There is no video on my page (

Comment: Probably, the video should be in the `public` (`/public/bg_video/club_v.mp4`) folder, with other static assets

Comment: and i must write the path like : public\css\style\vide_v ?

Comment: or i can just put in there video and write just "video_v.mp4" as i did ?

Comment: If you put it in `public/video_v.mp4` - just `video_v.mp4` should work

Comment: Ok, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move video file (e.g `video_v.mp4`) into `public` folder (where you have other static assets like `css-files`).

Then

```
<source src="video_v.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

should work.